# Could not open a socket to the SMTP server 13:permission denied

Tags: sockets, smtp

I am using a forum script that utilizes SMTP to send emails. It used to work fine, but all of the sudden I am getting this error:

```
Could not open a socket to the SMTP server 13:permission denied
```

This is all I get, but why is that? I am on running it on CentOS Linux 7.3.1611.

Comment: This question needs to be updated with the actual script code and probably the command that attempts to launch (if called from CLI).

Comment: You are getting a permission error while creating/configuring the socket prior to connect. SMTP doesn't come into play until after the socket is connected to the server. This is a common error to see when running an SMTP *server*, since the default SMTP port is 25, which is in Linux's reserved port range that requires admin rights. But, an SMTP *client* should not typically be getting this error, unless it is trying to bind its socket to a local port that is restricted. A *client* shouldn't be explicitly binding its local port, unless firewall restrictions require it.

Comment: Thank you but how can I solve it? I have always used the script and everything is the same since I didnt change anything so I dont understand why all of the sudden is this happening.